# Safari Presentation Mode command line

Tags: safari, macos, google-chrome, fullscreen

I created a HTML5 presentation that I would like to run fullscreen (no toolbars, just viewport). With a simple command line I can open the presentation in fullscreen on Chrome:

```
open "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" --args --kiosk http://192.168.1.1
```

However, because the presentation uses some heavy HTML5 and jQuery, the animations run much smoother in Safari (optimized for the MacBook).

Is there any way (or command line argument) I can open Safari in true fullscreen mode on Yosemite without toolbars or address bars?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an AppleScript like that to do it.

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
delay 3 --adjust to your needs
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "View"
                tell menu "View"
                    click menu item "Hide Toolbar"
                end tell
            end tell
            tell menu bar item "View"
                tell menu "View"
                    click menu item "Hide Status Bar"
                end tell
            end tell
            tell menu bar item "View"
                tell menu "View"
                    click menu item "Enter Full Screen"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Save it with the name you want, and then run with `osascript your-script`.

Comment: I would throw in some 'try' statements to work through if they are already hidden.  Otherwise the above worked.

Comment: The problem is that Safari 8 on Yosemite always seems to keep showing the tabs bar. I know this can't be changed through the menu but I was hoping that (like with Chrome) it might be possible to enter some kind of 'Presentation' or 'Kiosk' mode using command line arguments.

Comment: No. Safari does not have this kind of options.